# how can we know which pts in /dev/pts mapping to which ip address?

Tags: terminal, users, session

Can anyone explain , how can we detect which `ssh session` belong to which ip address using `/dev/pts` directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `who`. This is brittle but it may help you:

```
who | awk '{print $2,$NF}' |grep -v '(:[0-9]'
```

- `who` prints a list of logged in users
- `awk` extracts the second and the last fields (space-separated). The second field is the user's pseudo terminal device and the last field is the display they're connecting from (or IP for a remote connection).
- The `grep` filter removes lines for users connecting from the local display (any terminal devices that local users are logged in at).

The `who` command itself should be present on any POSIX-compliant system. I can't vouch for its output format being consistent on different systems, though. This will also break if a user name contains spaces.